# C multiple operations in single row

Tags: c, reference, integer

I would like to do this in one line (C programming language):

```
int x = index >> 8;
int y = x < 10 ? x+1 : x+2;
```

Is it possible? How do I reference to value before ? sign, if I don't have it stored in separate integer?

```
"int y = (index >> 8) < 10 ? [what]+1 : [what]+2;"
```

Comment: Clarity is more important than brevity.  In this case, two lines is better than one.  The `[what]` bits would have to be `(index >> 8)` parenthesized, and would be less clear with the repetition, even though the optimizer would probably optimize for you to approximately what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to repeat the expression:

```
int y = (index >> 8) < 10 ? (index >> 8) + 1 : (index >> 8) + 2;
```

It's not very nice, or readable, so I don't get why you must do it this way. There's no built-in way in the language to reference the expression before the `?`. Since expressions can have side-effects in C, it would be quite hairy if there was.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have this expression is the best you can get there without code repetition.
If you absolutely need it to be a single string, you can simply do the following:

```
int y = (index >> 8) < 10 ? (index >> 8)+1 : (index >> 8)+2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because C makes no distinction between whitespace characters, you can have it in a single line:

```
int x = index >> 8; int y = x < 10 ? x+1 : x+2;
```

...which is completely valid C.

However your `y` and `x` values are not inter-dependent, so you can simplify the expression to just `y`:

```
 int y = index >> 8; y = y < 10 ? y+1 : y+2;
```

If your `y` already exists, you can make use of the little-used comma operator to eliminate the semi-colon and reduce it to a single statement:

```
y = ( y = index >> 8 ), y < 10 ? y+1 : y+2;
```

Note that you cannot use the comma operator inside a value declaration statement because in that context it becomes the sequence separator.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not useful to try to optimize source code in this way. C does not specify what specific operations the computer must perform; C specifies what results a program must achieve. (By means of the “as if” model in C. The program the compiler produces must produce results as if you stepped through the specific operations you wrote, but those results can actually be obtained by any sequence of instructions the implementation chooses. The program only needs to reproduce results, not mechanisms.)

Generally, you should write your code to be clear, and you should allow the optimizer in the compiler to do its job of performing the calculations efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, by removing the ternary. The shift being equivalent to a division by 256, we can compare the value also before the shifting.

```
int y = (index >> 8) + 1 + (index >= 2560);
```

Of course, index should be positive for this to work.

EDIT: the expression has also the advantage of having no temporary write access and no sequence point.

Comment: While this works for the example used, it won't work for all forms of similar expressions.

Comment: It was to show that sometimes by mathematical transformations you can find much better expressions. The compilers sometimes do these kind of things but they are often constrained by rules of generality that they can not solve (like the impact on oveflow, precision and signedness). The programmer does know more normally and can replace by expressions that can be applied in the case.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using this form :

```
int y = (y = index >> 8) < 10 ? y+1 : y+2;
```

Here, y get assigned the temporary value of index >> 8, so you can reuse that value after the ? operator.

And contrary to David's similar answer, this form work inside a value declaration statement as well.